# How to identify if a categorical feature is redundant

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm currently doing a demand forecasting task, and I found that some products can be categorized as weekend and weekday products (i.e. products that are bought more frequently during the weekend/weekday).

I'm planning to add a weekend indicator as a binary feature (1 if Saturday or Sunday; 0 otherwise). If I add the actual days of the week (Mon, Tues, Wed, etc) as binary features, does that make the weekend indicator redundant? Or does it contribute additional value to the forecasting task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the feature will be redundant as it is a (linear) function of two other features. But it may impact the performance of the model (in good, or in bad).

As often, it will depend on the model you are using. A genuine linear regression is likely to fail in presence of features which are linearly dependent. However, tough this feature is redundant, it may provide an improvement of your performance with other models*. The best way to know is to try with and without it and observe the performance with cross validation (or on a test set).